# Ellipsoid coefficient normalization to get semi-axes

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadrics

I have an ellipsoid. Its quadric equation is :

> $Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + Dxy + Eyz + Fxz + Gx + Hy + Iz + J = 0$

The quadratic part of the quadric equation can be expressed with a matrix :

\begin{bmatrix}A&D/2&F/2\\D/2&B&E/2\\F/2&E/2&C\end{bmatrix}

I read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid that the eigenvalues of the above matrix are the reciprocals of the squares of the semi-axes of my ellipsoid.

But because the quadric equation is homogeneous, the coefs (A, B, C...) are not important, only their ratio is. But different values of the coefs lead to different values of the eigenvalues (but the eigenvectors remain always the same).

Have I to normalize the coefs to something to get the right eigenvalues ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already noticed that there is a problem with the normalization. Let's look at the simple case, where only $A,B,C,J$ are non-zero. In that case, the equation for your ellipse is $$Ax^2+By^2+Cz^2+J=0$$
You want to get to $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$
That means you need to move $J$ top the right hand side, then divide everything by $-J$. In that case $$\frac1{a^2}=-\frac AJ$$
and similar for the other coefficients.

The problem is just a little more complicated when your ellipse is off center. If you write $$(\mathbf x-\mathbf v)^TM(\mathbf x-\mathbf v)=1$$ you notice that the center $\mathbf v$will shift the value of $J$

Comment: Thanks. What if J=0 ?

Comment: $J=\mathbf{v}^{T}M\mathbf{v}-1$ if the ellipsoid is represented as a [quadric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#As_quadric), so $J=-1$ if it is centered at the origin, but I have the impression that the OP wants to get at something different, however I don't really understand why " the coefs (A, B, C...) are not important, only their ratio is"?

Comment: @PeterMelech If you use homogeneous coordinates, the original equation can be written in the form $\mathbf x^TQ\mathbf x=0$, where $Q$ is a symmetric $4\times4$ matrix. Multiplying $Q$ by a nonzero scalar doesn’t affect the solution set and it’s the $9$ unique ratios among its entries that determine the quadric, not the specific values of those entries, i.e., the matrix is homogeneous.

Comment: @amd Thanks! I think now I understand the OP's point better....I guess the homogeneous coordinates as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Normal_form_of_projective_quadrics) don't fulfill the "eigenvalue-semi-axis" relationship

Comment: I understand my mistake, i try to search the semi axis of an ellipsoid which in not centered at the origin, so it doesn't work. I'll try to center it.